# Nullable DateTime with Html.EditorFor() ASP.NET MVC helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, nullable

I have a `DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }` in my asp.net mvc viewmodel, and I tried to do `Html.EditorFor(x => x.StartDate)` in my view. I got an error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'System.DateTime'.

Anything good way to get around this without creating a non-nullable surrogate property on my viewmodel?

Comment: There must more to this issue.  It definitely works for me (using it daily to show empty dates).  What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: Anything else special here maybe Editor, Display templates or partial views?

Comment: oops, turns out it was throwing the exception on EditorFor, not LabelFor

Comment: What EditorTemplate do you have associated with `DateTime?` or with the property it does not seem to handle a null model passed to it.

Comment: ah, that's probably it. I totally forgot I had a different EditorTemplate for DateTime. Feel free to submit an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be the answer to your issue:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeNullableDecimal, "NullableDecimalTemplate" )%>
```

Credit:
[ASP.NET MVC 2 - Html.EditorFor a nullable type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323744/asp-net-mvc-2-html-editorfor-a-nullable-type)

Answer (score 4):

Most probably you have defined datetime editor template like this - `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Datetime.cshtml`

```
@model Datetime
//etc
```

Change model to take nullable datetime

```
@model Datetime?
//etc
```